# Python parse html file without losing dependancies

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to parse this html page to get the number of airlines per région and country and city:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports

I’m using beautifulsoup to get data but the problem that I got data seperatly. For example all airlines without region, country and city.
I’m usine the method findall to get special headers.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

GLOBAL =[]
l=[]
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
k=[]
G=[[]]
T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})

T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})
for line in T:
    if line.name == 'h2':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            A=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'h3':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            B=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'ul':
        if B:
            city=line.findAll('a')
            for i in city:
                if i.get('title'):
                    if i.get('title').endswith('Airport') == True:
                        D=[]
                        for i in city:
                            D.append(i.text)
                        l.append([A,B,D])
                        break


for k in l:
    print(k)
```

The ouput is:

```
[region,country,[cities,listArilines]]
```

But the expected ouput:

```
[region,country,[city,listAirlines]]
```

So, I have two problems:
 - I lost dependecies between city and its airlines.
 - For some region/country, I have rather table like Europe, that I don't know how to parse it to extract it as the expected ouput.

I need your help
Thank you

Comment: Please provide your expected output and provide some code trial how you are fetching the data?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: page display nested elements so maybe you should run nested `findall()` to get nested subelements.

Comment: I edited my post by adding my code and expected output. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some lines in your code but I think you will have the right values now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

GLOBAL =[]
l=[]
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
k=[]
G=[[]]
T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})

T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})
for line in T:
    if line.name == 'h2':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            A=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'h3':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            B=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'ul':
        if B:
            cities = line.findChildren('li')
            for i in cities:
                if i.find('a'):
                    cityname = i.find('a').get('title')
                    airlines = i.findAll('li')
                    if airlines:
                        for a in airlines:
                            if a.find('a'):
                                D=[]
                                D.append(cityname)
                                D.append(a.text)
                                l.append([A,B,D])


for k in l:
    print(k)
```

**EDIT**

I you want only one line per city, with a list of airlines, you just have to do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hub_airports").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")

GLOBAL =[]
l=[]
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
k=[]
G=[[]]
T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})

T=soup.findAll({'h2','h3','ul'})
for line in T:
    if line.name == 'h2':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            A=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'h3':
        REG = line.findAll('span', {'class': 'mw-headline'})
        if REG:
            B=REG[0].get('id')
    if line.name == 'ul':
        if B:
            cities = line.findChildren('li')
            for i in cities:
                if i.find('a'):
                    cityname = i.find('a').get('title')
                    airlines = i.findAll('li')
                    if airlines:
                        D = []
                        D.append(cityname)
                        for a in airlines:
                            if a.find('a'):
                                D.append(a.text)
                        l.append([A,B,D])


for k in l:
    print(k)
```